# Trying to animate a drop from a faucet with CALayers

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, caanimation

I'm trying to make a UIView subclass that shows a water faucet with a drop that keeps growing and then dropping. The more experiments I run with the different parts, the more I get confused.

I created two graphics:

[image]
[image]

I created a UIView class:

```
class ValvebeatView: UIView {
    var faucet = CALayer()
    var drip = CALayer()

    func _init() {
        self.faucet.contents = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "faucet").cgImage
        self.drip.contents = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "droplet").cgImage
        self.layer.insertSublayer(self.drip, above: nil)
        self.layer.insertSublayer(self.faucet, above: self.drip)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self._init()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        self._init()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.faucet.frame = self.bounds
        self.drip.frame = self.bounds
    }

    func startDrop() {

    }
}
```

If I add this view in my app, I get something that looks like this:

[image]

which is just right. But as soon as I try to experiment with changing the appearance of the drop, nothing works as expected. What I've tried/learned so far:

- Setting the `drip.contentScale` doesn't seem to do anything. The documentation makes it sound like that's just a hint anyway?
- I played with `contentsRect` which seems to change it, but after reading the docs, it seems to indicate that it's determine the subsection of the drop image that is shown. I want to show all of the drop, I just want to start small, make it swell, and then switch to translating it downwards.
- Various transform options (scale then translate) seem like the right way to do things. But that doesn't produce the right result either. For example, if I set up a tap gesture to `self.valvebeatView.drip.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.1, 0.1, 1)`, it temporarily swells 10x, and then reverts to original size. But what's even weirder, is if I instead do `self.valvebeatView.drip.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(10.0, 10.0, 1)`, it does the same thing?!?!? Why didn't it at least shrink and then revert to the original shape?

I've wondered if it is because my gravity is set to the default (which is resize). But when I change that to center, the original drop is way out of size.

The short of my question, is which hooks (transform, position, etc?) do I want to use animate my drop growing from a small scale to normal, and then falling downwards.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you really do want to persist in doing this with a layer and layer animation instead of the much easier approach of using a view and view animation.

Then of the rather wacky ideas you've listed, only changing the `transform` and possibly also the `position` (if the idea is also to move the drop) is right. You need to learn about CABasicAnimation. To combine growth of the drop with falling of the drop in a nice coordinated way, use CAAnimationGroup.

Comment: But if the idea is create a steady stream of drops, this might better be a job for a CAEmitter.

Comment: I'm reasonably confident with how to to do this with two stacked image views. Then just animate either the transform or even the frame/bounds of the drop. I thought layers were the "preferred" way to do things though. My real frustration is the experience I had with just changing the transform, long before I apply any of the animation classes (I've used those quite a bit to date, but usually only for rotation).

Comment: That doesn’t change my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 func startDrop() {

    self.drip.contentsGravity = kCAGravityCenter
    let center = CGPoint.init(x: self.frame.width / 2.0, y: self.frame.height / 2.0)
    let scaleAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation.init(keyPath: "contentsScale")
    scaleAnimation.values = [3, 1, 1 ]
    scaleAnimation.keyTimes = [0,0.2, 1]
    scaleAnimation.duration = 3
    scaleAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    scaleAnimation.repeatCount = Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude
    let positionAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation.init(keyPath: "position")
    positionAnimation.values = [center  , center, CGPoint.init(x:center.x ,y:center.y * 2) ]
    positionAnimation.keyTimes = [0,0.2, 1]
    positionAnimation.duration = 3
    positionAnimation.repeatCount = Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude
    positionAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

    self.drip.add(scaleAnimation, forKey: "scale")
    self.drip.add(positionAnimation, forKey: "pos")

}
```